# SSRS: Use Go to URL to open email with report embedded in body

Tags: reporting-services, outlook, action

How do you use the Action Options of a Text Box Property to open an email message with the report embedded in the body?

We're trying to automate a task, by where a user can filter records using multi-select parameters and then email a report to some external clients. However, we need to be able to attach supportive documentation on top of what's embedded in the email.

Currently, I have it set up to where the report calls itself and emails the report as wanted to the user, who then has to open it, attach whatever documentation is needed and then forward it to the actual recipients.

Any help is appreciated.

Using Visual Studio 2008, SQL Server 2014

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using? Standard or Enterprise? If Enterprise, you could potentially look at triggering a Data Driven subscription to send the e-mail out

Comment: Hi. I'm using Standard. But I already have a subscription sending the email out. The problem is, I don't want the email to "Send", I want it to "Open" so we can add attachments, verify content, etc.

Thank you

Comment: In that case.. why not send it to yourself and do what you need to and forward as required.. just an idea

Comment: Thank you Harry. That's exactly what we're doing now. The problem is, it's clunky and seems kind of band-aided. If it were for me, I probably wouldn't care...but this is something that's being rolled out to a different department.

I'm trying very hard to use the "Action" "Go to URL" with "MailTo" option...as that's the only way I know how to actually open Microsoft Outlook. I can pass parameter variables to my subject just fine...I just can't figure out how to embed the report itself into the body of the email.

Tips?

Comment: Embedding report in the body of an email is the easy part. Use the MHTML (Web Archive) as your Render Format along with Email as destination. This works a treat for me.( assuming you are still suing a subscription to trigger the email)

Comment: Yes...but that only works with the Subscription. I want the email to open so the user can make changes BEFORE sending.

Basically, I want to click a link in the report...have that link then open an Outlook message with the "To", "Subject" and "Body" populated. I have the "To" and the "Subject" working...but the "Body" only shows a link to the report, instead of the report itself.

Comment: I think you are probably out of luck to do something like that straight out of the box. I do a similar thing.. but I send the report to the person triggering the report.. it has all the details.. including the email address it is supposed to go to.. but in the subject field.. the user simply has to review and then cut that email address, hit forward and paste the address into the TO field.. send ..not ideal.. but my users are happy with it..